# Why do diastereomers have different physical and chemical properties?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

While going through my book (*Organic Chemistry, Paula Bruice*) I came across the following line:

> We have seen that enantiomers have identical physical properties. They
> also have  identical chemical properties—that is, they react with a
> given achiral reagent at the same  rate. Diastereomers, on the other
> hand, have different physical properties (meaning different melting
> points, boiling points, solubilities, specific rotations, and so on)
> and different  chemical properties —that is, they react with a given
> achiral reagent at different rates.

There seems to be no further explanation about why this is so, and I am unable to figure out the reason behind the difference in physical and chemical properties of diastereomers. I do understand why it would be so in the case of cis-trans isomerism, but not in the case of optical isomers. 
What would be a plausible explanation for this? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your title and your text say different things. Title "Why do **diastereomers** have different physical and chemical properties?". Text "I am unable to figure out the reason behind the difference in physical and chemical properties of **enantiomers**. [...] **optical isomers**".

Comment: In any case, the answer to the question you are asking in the title is "asymmetry". If you could not tell left from right, you would not be able to distinguish L-tartaric acid from D-tartaric acid. On the other hand, you would be able to distinguish L or D from meso-tartaric acid, e.g. by the fact that in a particular standard drawing of the molecule the two OH groups are on the same side vs on opposite sides. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartaric_acid. An achiral reagent is like a person who cannot tell left from right.

Comment: @user6376297 thanks, I have corrected the typo in the question, I intended to ask about diastereomers. Your answer was quite helpful, thanks a lot